# express the curvature equation in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to express the curvature equation in polar coordinates. So I am setting it up as a change of variables with $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$ of the equation:

$$K = \frac{y''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}}$$

We can get $y'$ to be

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}sin(\theta)+r\cos(\theta)}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)}$$

Now I am wondering what would be the easiest way to the $y''$. My initial idea was to

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\frac{dy}{dx}] = \frac{d}{d\theta}[\frac{dy}{dx}]\frac{d \theta}{dx}$$

Where $$\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}} = \frac{1}{-r\sin(\theta)}$$

But the second part is very annoying to compute. Is there another way I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this to be a parametric curve, and use the formula for the curvature of a parametrically defined curve. This is done [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-curvature-of-plane-polar-curves).